# Wordpress navbar, i have a problem with java script, because i had to style my own navbar, as it is custom theme

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have a problem with my navbar. I can't seem to get the logic of it, i need my navbar to close when i click somewhere outside of it. I will put what i tried and my HTML structure below. I made this first `eventlistener`, which only closes the dropdown when the next one opens, and i cant seem to work around a problem around it.

```js
let menuItem = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item-has-children');

// console.log(menuItem);
let menuItemLink = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item-has-children > a');
let subMenu = document.querySelectorAll('.sub-menu');
for(let i = 0; i < menuItem.length; i++){
    menuItem[i].addEventListener('click',(e) => {
        if(e.target){
            subMenu[i].classList.toggle('show');
            console.log(menuItemLink);
        }
        
        for(let j = 0; j < menuItem.length; j++){
            if(j != i){
                subMenu[j].classList.remove('show');
            } 
        }
       
    });
    
}
window.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
    for(let i = 0; i < subMenu.length; i++){
        if(subMenu[i].classList.contains('show')){
            for(let j = 0; j < subMenu[i].classList.length;j++)
            {

                if(j != i){
                subMenu[j].classList.remove('show');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
})
```

```html
<div id="navbarNavDropdown" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <div class="menu-main-nav-container">
        <ul id="menu-main-nav" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-1973" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1973" data-ol-has-click-handler="">
                <a>Bookmakers</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-1974" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-operator menu-item-1974"><a href="http://localhost:10018/operators/toto/">toto</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-1975" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-operator menu-item-1975"><a href="http://localhost:10018/operators/ze-turf/">Ze Turf</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-1976" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-operator menu-item-1976"><a href="http://localhost:10018/operators/fair-play/">Fair play</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-1977" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-operator menu-item-1977"><a href="http://localhost:10018/operators/bingo-ball/">Bingo Ball</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-1978" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-operator menu-item-1978"><a href="http://localhost:10018/operators/ggpoker/">GGpoker</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-1979" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-operator menu-item-1979"><a href="http://localhost:10018/operators/holland-casino/">Holland Casino</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-1980" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-operator menu-item-1980"><a href="http://localhost:10018/operators/betcity/">betCity</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-1981" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-operator menu-item-1981"><a href="http://localhost:10018/operators/bet365/">bet365</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-1982" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1982"><a href="#">Bonuses</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1983" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1983"><a href="#">Strategies</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1984" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1984"><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-2063" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-2063"><a href="http://localhost:10018/category/news/">News</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1985" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1985" data-ol-has-click-handler="">
                <a>Tools</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-1986" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1986"><a href="#">System Bets Calculator</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-1987" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1987"><a href="#">Injured and suspended</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-1988" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1988"><a href="#">Glossary</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-1990" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1990" data-ol-has-click-handler="">
                <a>Betting Tips</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-2010" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-2010"><a href="http://localhost:10018/category/betting-categories/bundesliga/">Bundesliga</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-2011" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-2011"><a href="http://localhost:10018/category/betting-categories/champions-league/">Champions League</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-2012" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-2012"><a href="http://localhost:10018/category/betting-categories/eredvisie/">Eredvisie</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-2013" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-2013"><a href="http://localhost:10018/category/betting-categories/europa-league/">Europa League</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-2014" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-2014"><a href="http://localhost:10018/category/betting-categories/premier-league/">Premier League</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-2015" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-2015"><a href="http://localhost:10018/category/betting-categories/primera-divison/">Primera Divison</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-2016" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-2016"><a href="http://localhost:10018/category/betting-categories/serie-a/">Serie A</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-1991" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1991"><a href="#">Something</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an overlay between the page content and the menu that catches the event of clicking outside the menu. This can be done with **z-index** and adding and HTML element for the overlay.

```js
function toggleMenu() {
  var menu = document.getElementById('navbarNavDropdown');
   if(menu.classList.contains('show')){
    menu.classList.remove('show')
   }else{
   menu.classList.add('show');
   }
   
  var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
   if(overlay.classList.contains('show')){
    overlay.classList.remove('show')
   }else{
   overlay.classList.add('show');
   }
}
```

```css
.page-content {
  z-index: 1;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
}

.overlay.show {
  display: block;
}

#navbarNavDropdown {
  background: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  right: -300px;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: .5s slide;
}

#navbarNavDropdown.show {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-content">
  <div>
    <h1>Here goes normal content</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
    <a href="#" id="opener" onclick="toggleMenu()">Open menu</a>
  </div>
  <div id="navbarNavDropdown"> ... your menu content ... </div>
  <div id="overlay" class="overlay" onclick="toggleMenu()"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you do it in Vanilla JS, as i need to do it in Vanilla

Comment: I've updated the code for Vanilla JS :)